# Highlighting a cell on click and forwarding to a new cell

Tags: excel, vba

So, it's a new week, and I've got new ideas for improving things.  Part of what I do is send out reports to individual offices and departments all over the place; these offices in turn are *supposed* to go through the information and note inconsistencies.  As with everything in life, this turns out to be more trouble than anything else. In an effort to make it a little bit more painless (I hope) I want to try somethinga little different for them.  What I would like to do is set up something within the worksheet that the individuals receive that does two things:

1. First, I would like to set up the worksheet so that when the user
   clicks on a cell the cell is highlighted;
2. Second, after the cell highlights then the activebox would
   automatically transfer to a "comments" box at the end of the row
   where the user would enter their comments as to why the cell in
   question was highlighted; and
3. Third, assuming that someone will make a mistake and highlight
   something by mistake I would like to add the additional function
   that if a user selects a cell that is highlighted then it would
   clear the highlight from the cell.

Possible? Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMax is correct in identifying the flaw in that you cannot edit a cell if it changes color and selects a comments cell every time you click on it. The best way around this problem is to change the color only on double-click. I would also define the selected row/column and see if they fall within a table's range (instead of using Application.Intersect) but that's just personal preference

Something like...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Beforedoubleclick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim TargRow as Variant
Dim TargCol as Variant

TargRow = target.Row
TargCol = target.Column

'Define Header, FirstCol, CommentCol, LastCol as required to define your table/range where you wish these changes to be made. CommentCol is the cell in which comments should be made

    If TargRow > Header And TargCol > FirstCol and TargCol < LastCol Then
        If Cells(TargRow,TargCol).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then 'change color as required to match background
        Cells(TargRow,TargCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'change color as required; this makes them red
        Cells(TargRow,CommentCol).Select
        Else
        Cells(TargRow,TargCol).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 'match color from start of IF statement
        End If
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that we disable events so no other code can be triggered by us selecting a different cell. This is an absolute necessity when implementing the Worksheet_SelectionChange event, less so with the BeforeDoubleClick event

It's very important to consider how you trigger macros and how they give the user flexibility. This [Excel help video](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/starting-macros-buttons-events.php) provides a reasonable introduction

Comment: I've had a little time to work at this again, and I was able to get the highlighting done much easier than expected. What I have now for highlighting is:
`Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 
    
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 
       Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 
          ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 
       Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 
    End If 
    Cancel = True 
    End Sub`
This does what I have intended, which is to highlight (or remove a highlight from) the cell.

Comment: If you put the code in the sheet itself, you don't need to declare 'Sh as Object'...then the reason for identifying the target row in the longer example is so we can select the comment cell in that line. The rest is designed to make the code robust and may not be necessary

Comment: Well, clearly I'm doing something wrong here. I scrapped what I had in the comments and inserted yours into the worksheet, instead of mine in the workbook. I assume I am messing up with defining things so I'll need to work at that.

Comment: Header, FirstCol, CommentCol and LastCol should all end up being numbers e.g. if FirstCol is Column A, then FirstCol = 1. I would normally define them with reference to named ranges but I would use numbers until you get it working

Comment: Alright, got everything working as intended finally.  I like the use of numbers to define those values better anyways; It juss feels simpler to me and makes it a lot easier for me to attempt to explain to others.

Answer (score 1):

What you can (and probably have to) use is the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event procedure:

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220977(v=office.11).aspx) for how it works.
You also should have a look at Chip Pearson's [page about events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

When the user changes the selection, you should check wheter you are in the right cells (using `Intersect`) and if so, change the `Target` background color and change the `ActiveCell` to the one where you should put comments.
Btw, you can check if the cell is aldreay highlighted before moving to another cell.

The main drawback of this method is that it will move the Excel Selection **every time** the user **clicks on a corresponding cell**. A solution would be to tell the user to use the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key and to navigate with arrows. See [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001217.htm) on how it works.